# Getting error on package.xml when running "catkin_ make"

Tags: ros, catkin-make, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just started with ROS and I am following one of my first beginner tutorial "*Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)*".

I am receiving an error when I run **catkin_make** or **catkin_make install**

---

**This is my terminal:**

```
lucadg@luca-Inspiron-3543:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make install
Base path: /home/lucadg/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/lucadg/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/lucadg/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/lucadg/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/lucadg/catkin_ws/install
**Invalid package manifest "/home/lucadg/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/package.xml": The manifest contains invalid XML:
mismatched tag: line 60, column 2**
```

---

Below a copy of my package.xml file which I checked and everything seems to be ok, line 60 is the last word, the closing tag of package.

---

**This is my package.xml**

```
<?xml version="3.0"?>
<package>

  <name>beginner_tutorials</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>

  <description>The beginner_tutorials package</description>

  <!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag -->
  <!-- Example:  -->
  <!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> -->
  <maintainer email="lucadigiammarino@hotmail.it">Luca Di Giammarino</maintainer>


  <!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag -->
  <!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
  <!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 -->
  <license>BSD</license>


  <!-- Url tags are optional, but mutiple are allowed, one per tag -->
  <!-- Optional attribute type can be: website, bugtracker, or repository -->
  <!-- Example: -->
  <!-- <url type="website">http://wiki.ros.org/beginner_tutorials</url> -->


  <!-- Author tags are optional, mutiple are allowed, one per tag -->
  <!-- Authors do not have to be maintianers, but could be -->
  <!-- Example: -->
  <!-- <author email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</author> -->


  <!-- The *_depend tags are used to specify dependencies -->
  <!-- Dependencies can be catkin packages or system dependencies -->
  <!-- Examples: -->
  <!-- Use build_depend for packages you need at compile time: -->
  <!--   <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend> -->
  <!-- Use buildtool_depend for build tool packages: -->
  <!--   <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend> -->
  <!-- Use run_depend for packages you need at runtime: -->
  <!--   <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend> -->
  <!-- Use test_depend for packages you need only for testing: -->
  <!--   <test_depend>gtest</test_depend> -->
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_generation<run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime<run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
  </export>
</package>
                                                                                                                           60,1          Bot
```

---

Thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242744/getting-error-on-package.xml-when-running-%22catkin_-make%22/) by [lucadg](https://answers.ros.org/users/27866/lucadg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-08-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like a couple of your dependencies don't have good close tags:

```
<run_depend>message_generation<run_depend>
<run_depend>message_runtime<run_depend>
```

Sometimes the XML parser doesn't realize there's an error until it gets to a close tag, so you have to look at the error message too, not just the line number.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-31**:
Also:

> ```
> <?xml version="3.0"?>
> ```

Was that auto-generated @lucadg? Afaik, there are only two valid values for `version`: `1.0` and `1.1` (see [wikipedia/XML - Versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Versions) fi).

**Comment by [lucadg](https://answers.ros.org/users/27866/lucadg/) on 2016-08-31**:
Thank you @ahendrix, I thought that was the right line number. Also I've changed the xml `version` by mistake, it should be `1.0`

**Comment by [michael_kong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29170/michael_kong/) on 2017-01-26**:
have you solved this problem? I have met the same one

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-26**:
Yes, the error was that some of the closing tags were incorrect. Read your XML carefully and make sure that there's a close tag for every open tag.

**Comment by [hpurohit](https://answers.ros.org/users/27412/hpurohit/) on 2017-03-06**:
Thanks for the solution